# SwiftUI List View Unselectable Rows Within the List

Tags: listview, navigation, swiftui

In my latest SwuiftUI app, depending upon the option selected, one of three different list views are created.  The each of the three possible list contains all the rows upon display.  However, for all three lists, none of the first four rows are "selectable" to navigate to the detail view.  All of the remaining rows are selectable and navigate properly to the detail view.

Here is the relevant code:

```
struct Accounts: View {

    init(){
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        UITableView.appearance().tableFooterView = UIView()
    }

    // MARK: - Propertiers
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation

    @State private var accounts = ["New Account", "Account 1", "
Account 2", "Account 3", "Account 4", "Account 5", "Account 6"] // placeholder data

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            ZStack {

                BackgroundView(majorColorR: 255, majorColorG: 255, majorColorB: 255, minorColorR: 204, minorColorG: 0, minorColorB: 0)

                VStack {

                    AppTitle()

                    List(accounts, id: \.self) { account in
                        NavigationLink(destination: ShowAccount(account: account)) {
                           Text("\(account)")
                           .font(.headline)
                           .foregroundColor(.black)
                       }
                    }

                    Spacer()


                    Button(action: {
                        self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }) {
                        Text("Return to Main Menu")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                                .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 3)
                        )
                    }.padding(.bottom, 50)

                    Spacer()

                }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }

}
```

Comment: without any code ... maybe some clairvoyant can help you

Comment: I've posted the code but I don't think it is code related because the list populates properly with all the entries.  So each entry should be "select" active by SwiftUI without additional code.  Yet, only the fifth entry and above are "select" active.

Comment: there is a lot of potential trouble in your code. As the "first aid" remove .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) and try again.

Comment: Thanks.  Removing the .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) indeed resulted in the selectability of all the list rows.  However, the entire view now seems positioned with its "top" in the center of the screen.  Adding or moving the position of the bottom spacer doesn't help even though the documentation says a bottom spacer pushes everything to the top.

Comment: see my answer ... rewrite it and follow some known pattern.

Answer (score 0):

try to run this example

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("A")
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("alfa")) {
                    Text("row alfa")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("beta")) {
                    Text("row beta")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("gama")) {
                    Text("row gama")

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

What is the expected result? If You answer that it is screen with the single text A in the middle of it, you are right!

Rotate the device and you see  ....

[image]

**Your layout is 'complex' and maybe some small rearrange of your code could help ... But I suggest you rewrite it from the ground!**